# How can do I install any software using ubuntu terminal by knowing their name only

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, sudo

**Installation Any Software On Ubuntu**

I want to install any software usinh *sudo* and *apt* from terminal. If I know only the software name from their official site, then is it possible to perform this action?

Comment: No. You need to know the package name.

Comment: @mikewhatever There is a question for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for a package called "packagename":

`apt search packagename`

This gives you a list of packages that match the search term "packagename"

Choose the one that you would like to install. For example, to install pip for python 3:

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

To read more about the apt command:

`man apt`

Answer (score 1):

You can search for packages providing a file with

```
dpkg -S file
```

and you can search for packages and keywords with.

```
apt-cache search
```

Read

```
man dpkg apt-search
```